# Coveo cloud indexing error with "NameResolutionFailure" error code

Tags: coveo

I am using `Coveo for Sitecore 4 450 build`. Noticing this error only on few environments. I looked up there is no `CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildException` entry in the coveo configs. Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=Coveo_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.Exceptions.CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildException: An error occurred while querying documents to delete. ---> Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClientException: Failed to obtain resource located at 'http://devsite/coveo/rest?pipeline='.
[BEGIN RESPONSE BODY]{"message":"The remote name could not be resolved: 'platform.cloud.coveo.com'","errorCode":"NameResolutionFailure"}[END RESPONSE BODY] ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClient.ExecuteRequest(String p_Url, Func`2 p_CreateRequest, Int64 p_CallId)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClient.HandleResponseException(WebException p_Exception, String p_Url, Int64 p_CallId)
at Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClient.ExecuteRequest(String p_Url, Func`2 p_CreateRequest, Int64 p_CallId)
at Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClient.PostRaw(String p_Url, String p_Body)
at Coveo.Framework.Utils.Rest.HttpClient.Post(String p_Url, String p_Body)
at Coveo.SearchServiceProvider.Rest.SearchQueryHelper.ExecuteQuery(QueryParams p_QueryParams, String p_Username)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.CleanUpAfterRebuild.CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildPerformer.ExecuteQuery(QueryParams p_QueryParams, String p_Username)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.CleanUpAfterRebuild.CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildPerformer.ExecuteQuery(QueryParams p_QueryParams, String p_Username)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.CleanUpAfterRebuild.CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildPerformer.QueryForDocumentToDelete(QueryParams p_QueryParams, String p_Username)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.CleanUpAfterRebuild.CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildPerformer.ExecuteCleanUp(String p_SourceName, DateTime p_LastRebuildDate, String p_Username, ICloudPlatformClient p_CloudPlatformClient, IManagedThreadPool p_ManagedThreadPool, HashSet`1 p_IndexedDocuments)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.DocumentManagement.CloudPlatformDocumentsHandler.ProcessStopRebuild(RebuildContext p_Context)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.DocumentManagement.CloudPlatformDocumentsHandler.StopRebuild(RebuildContext p_Context)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.DocumentManagement.CloudPlatformDocumentIndexer.StopRebuild(RebuildContext p_Context)
at Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.Communication.CloudPlatformCommunication.StopRebuild(RebuildContext p_Context)
at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndexBase.PerformRebuild(IProviderUpdateContext p_Context, Action`1 p_CrawlerAction)
at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndexBase.Rebuild(IndexingOptions p_IndexingOptions, IProviderUpdateContext p_Context, Action`1 p_CrawlerAction)
at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndex.TryPerformIndexingOperation(IndexingOptions p_IndexingOptions, Action p_Action)
at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndex.Rebuild()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this error in the stack trace `"The remote name could not be resolved: 'platform.cloud.coveo.com'","errorCode":"NameResolutionFailure"`, it looks like your Sitecore instance can't communicate with Coveo Cloud.

Have you tried accessing this URL directly from a browser in this same instance?

You should probably check if there are any errors in the Coveo Diagnostic Page, accessible from `YOUR_SITECORE_INSTANCE/sitecore%20modules/Web/Coveo/Admin/CoveoDiagnosticPage.aspx`

Comment: No errors in diagnostic page. I am able to access Coveo Cloud portal from the server.

Comment: What happens if you try to access `http://devsite/coveo/rest?pipeline=` ?

Comment: I am seeing the json object with results coming back.

Comment: Do you still have this error?

Since the `CleanUpIndexAfterRebuildPerformer` class calls the same endpoint as when you load `/coveo/rest`, we have to find the difference between the two environments. Is there a proxy/load balancer between your Sitecore instance and the Coveo Cloud endpoint..?

Comment: This is not happening anymore. Not sure what was the problem earlier. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: HI @flguillemette I am also getting error in serach indexes, when I run Coveo Diagnostics, not getting any error but when trying to hit the page http://Instance_name/coveo/rest..I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: This looks like another error, and a comment thread is not the best way to answer your question, you should probably enter a new question.